# Proper way of submitting parameters to parents in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am sorry for any language mistakes I might make. I am not a native speaker

I have a react component that fetches data from an API and then populates a table with those entries using the entrys.map function:

```
 render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>username</td>
                    <td>name</td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.state.users.map(user => <User key={user.userID} user={user} onClick={this.doSomething}/>)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In the child component User I then return the data from the API and also two buttons which on click should call the function doSomething of the parent.

I was looking for a way to call the function and also send parameters like which row it was and which of the two buttons were clicked.

I tried it with the `.bind()` function which send the needed parameter to the function but not which row it was and also I couldn't set the State in the parent component because `this` referred to the parameter I have send.

```
<input type='button' className='btn btn-xs btn-info' onClick={this.props.changeState.bind("week")}/>
```

So my question is now how to properly send the data back to the parent if there is a way to do so.

Comment: One way I thought of to do so is to call a different function (inside the parent) depending on wich button was clicked and have that function call the function wich actually does the changes but that seemed a bit to complicated and I hoped there would be a easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your User component, you can pass the data using bind like

```
<input type='button' className='btn btn-xs btn-info' onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this, "pass the row data here")}/>
```

And in your parent component, the function will be like this

```
doSomething = (data) => { // use arrow function
  console.log(data) // should appear pass the row data here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to bind your parent to the `doSomething` function

```
<User ... changeState={this.doSomething.bind(this)}/>
```

Then, in the child element, you can pass parameters to the function like this:

```
<input ... onClick={() => this.props.changeState("week")}/>
```

In the child element, `this.props.changeState` is the parent's `doSomething` function that has it's context set to the parent ( `.bind(this)`)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding to your problem, there are two buttons in each User Row and you have to pass which button and which row the user has clicked. For this, follow these steps:

step 1 :  make two functions in the parent and bind them in parent constructor. 
step 2 : pass these functions to the child component as props and use them on the onClick of the  respective button.

ex. 
Parent Component :

```
class Parent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.clickButton1 = this.clickButton1.bind(this);
            this.clickButton2 = this.clickButton2.bind(this);
        }

        clickButton1(row) {

        }

        clickButton2(row) {

        }

        render () {
            return (
                <User 
                    key={user.key}
                    clickButton1={this.clickButton1}
                    clickButton2={this.clickButton2} 
                />
            )
        }
    }
```

Child Component:

```
    class User extends Component {

        render() {
            const { key, clickButton1, clickButton1 } = this.props;
            <button onClick={ ()=> clickButton1(key) }>
                Button 1
            </button>
            <button onClick={ ()=> clickButton2(key) }>
                Button 2
            </button>
        }
    }
```

Here we are passing the key as a parameter to the function, and you can also get which button was clicked.